# Is a monotone function defined on any kind of interval measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Definition of **Measurable set**: A set $E$ measurable if $$m^*(A) = m^*(A \cap E) + m^*(A \cap E^c)$$ for every subset of $A$ of $\mathbb R$.

Definition of **Lebesgue measurable function**: Given a function $f: D \to \mathbb R$, defined on some domain $D$, we say that $f$ is Lebesgue measurable if $D$ is measurable and if, for each real $a$, the set $\{x\in D: f(x) \gt a\}$ is measurable.

So suppose $f(x)$ defined on $[a,b]$ is a monotone function, then $f(x)$ is a measurable function because $\{x∈[a,b] \mid f(x) > t, t ∈ \mathbb R\}$ must be one of the three situations--interval(closed or half open half closed), a single point set or $\emptyset$ while each of them is a measurable set.

My question is how about monotone $f(x)$ defined on $(a,b]$ or $(a,b)$ or $[a,b)$? Do kinds of interval domains affect $f$'s Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: If $E\subset\mathbb R$ is any measurable set and $f:E\to\mathbb R$ is monotone then $f$ is measurable. You can easily work this out - the set of points in $E$ where $f>a$ is the intersection of $E$ and a ____, so it's measurable because the intersection of two measurable sets is measurable.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: an interval like $(c, +\infty)$ or $[c, +\infty)$?

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229497/f-mathbfr-rightarrow-mathbfr-monotone-increasing-rightarrow-f-is

Comment: Yup${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Math1000: Awesome. A more general idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cite Math1000's comment:[$f: \mathbf{R} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ monotone increasing $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229497/f-mathbfr-rightarrow-mathbfr-monotone-increasing-rightarrow-f-is).

This is a more general question and Cass's answer is pretty clear and concise. And I cite his here "
If $f$ is increasing, the set {$x:f(x)>a$} is an **interval** for all $a$, hence measurable. By definition (Royden's), the function $f$ is measurable".

Combined with David C. Ullrich's comment, since $E$, be any of (a,b] or (a,b) or [a,b), measurable, $E ∩$ **the interval** is measurable that imply $f$ is Lebesgue measurable.