# If $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \Bbb R$ is monotone over all lines, can it be written as $h \circ l$ where $h$ is monotone and $l$ is a linear form?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, monotone-functions

Let be $f : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ monotone over all lines (not affine ones, but if there is an answer over affine lines, I'm interested.)

Is it possible to find $h : \mathbb{R} \to \Bbb R$ monotone and $l : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ linear so that $f = h \circ l$ ?

I tried to look by supposing I have such a factorization, and as $\ker l$ is a hyperplane, I have $n - 1$ lines where $f$ is constant.
I tried to use the monotonicity condition by trying to compare $f(0)$ and over lines, but it didn't work.

Comment: The condition you've written doesn't make much sense, since it's equivalent to $$\forall (u',v)\in\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^n,\forall (t,t')\in\Bbb R^2,(t\le t'\to f(u't+v)\ge f(u't'+v))$$ by evaluating yours with $u:=-u'$.

Comment: You can simply say that a map from a line to line is monotone if it preserves betweenness.

Comment: @MoisheKohan So basically if you have two points, all points between must have their images between the images of the points?

Comment: That is right...

Comment: I suggest you clarify what a ‘line’ means in your question. Do you mean an affine line or a line through the origin as in the accepted answer. For affine lines your question is still open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your factorization implies that $f$ is measurable (see [$f: \mathbf{R} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ monotone increasing $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229497/f-mathbfr-rightarrow-mathbfr-monotone-increasing-rightarrow-f-is)). But you can construct a non measurable $f$ monotone over all lines.

EDIT 1: Construction of $f$.

Take
$$\varphi:{\Bbb R}^{n - 1}\longrightarrow{\Bbb R}$$ non measurable, and positive, $\eta$ monotone and positive. The function
$$g(x) = \varphi(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}) + \eta(x_n)$$ will be non measurable. Define $f$ in the upper half-space via a stereographic-projection-like bijection transforming the half-lines with constant $(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})$ (domain of $g$) in rays (domain of $f$). Define $f(0) = 0$. Define $f$ using symmetry in the open lower half-space. Complete $f$ in the rest of space respecting your condition. Done.

EDIT 2: The bijection.

$$\sigma:(x_1,\dots.x_n)\longmapsto\frac{(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},1)}{\|(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},1)\|}\,x_n,$$
$f$ in the open upper half-space:
$$f = g\circ\sigma^{-1}.$$

Comment: How to construct such a $f$ ?

Comment: @Raito, see the edit.

Comment: If you have time to do the "projection-like bijection" or an explicit formula (you don't have to do both), that'd be great, but I understood most of it, thank you!

Comment: Could you provide more detail: I did not understand which function you are using and why it is monotonic on every line. Incidentally, the question is unclear on what a "line" means. My reading is that it means an affine line (rather than a 1-dimensional linear subspace).

Comment: @MoisheKohan, see the edit for the explicit formula. The supposed consequence $f = h\circ l$ requires that "line" be interpreted as linear 1D-subspace.

Comment: I see. The real question I think, is about affine lines.