# Completeness of the measure space assumes continuity a.e. to imply measurability of functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, real-numbers, measurable-functions

I am studying Real analysis and I want to prove (or disprove) that (this is inspired by the fact that every continuous function is measurable)

> **Problem** If $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous a.e. then $f$ is measurable.

Applying the idea from [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229497/f-mathbfr-rightarrow-mathbfr-monotone-increasing-rightarrow-f-is) I believe it is true only when $X$ is complete, where the space is ***complete*** here means that every subset of $D$ of measure zero in that measure space is measurable. Then $\mathbb R$ is complete since every subset of the set of Lebesgue measure zero $A$ must be measurable.

**Q1** I am not sure if I understand this concept correctly. However, it seems false if $X$ is not complete and I use the example here (not sure if it is true please help me)

Let $Z\subset X$ be a measurable set of measure zero and $Z'\subset Z$ be a non-measurable subset of $Z$ (I don't know if there exists such space that this happens but I think it should exist for otherwise we may not need to use the "complete" term) and that
$$f(x) = \cases{1 & , $x\in Z'$ \cr 0 & ,  $x\in(X\setminus Z)\cup (Z\setminus Z')$}$$
This function is continuous a.e. (on $X\setminus Z$) but
$$\left\{x\in X; f(x)>\dfrac{1}{2}\right\}$$
is not measurable and $f$ is not a measurable function.

**Q2** What about the proof when $X$ is complete here, I am trying to use the idea on that link so that I can understand myself. Let $D$ be the set of measure zero of $X$. Define
$$f_1(x) = \cases{0 & , $x\in X\setminus D$ \cr f|_{D}(x) & ,  $x\in D$}$$
$$f_2(x) = \cases{0 & , $x\in D$ \cr f|_{X\setminus D}(x) & ,  $x\in X\setminus D$}$$
and each $f_1,f_2$ can be proven not hard that they are measurable functions (by using the fact that every subset of $D$ is measurable). Thus $f=f_1+f_2$ is measurable.

Comment: I think $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous a.e. means $\exists Z\subset X$ such that $\mu(Z)=0$ and $f$ is continuous on $X\setminus Z$.

Answer (score 0):

*Comment*
Perhaps it will help to define "continuous a.e.".  Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.  Let $\lambda$ be Lebesgue measure.  Let $\mathcal B$ be the sigma-algebra of Borel sets.  Two possible definitions:

(a)  Let $E = \{a \in \mathbb R : f \text{ is continuous at } a\}$.  We say "$f$ is continuous a.e." if $E \in \mathcal B$ and $\lambda(\mathbb R \setminus E) = 0$.

(b)  We say "$f$ is continuous a.e." if there exists a set $E \in \mathcal B$ such that $\lambda(\mathbb R \setminus E) = 0$ and the restriction $f\vert_{E}$ is a continuous function from $E$ to $\mathbb R$.

These two definitions are different.  For example, if $E\subset \mathbb R$ is measure zero but dense in $\mathbb R$, then the indicator function $f = \mathbf1_E$ satisfies (b) but not (a).  An example of such $E$ is $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: I meant (b) for the definition.